# What is the default gateway if spec say 255.255.255.1

Tags: networking, ip, gateway

If my ip is 60.70.80.90 and i have subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and the spec say that default gateway is 255.255.255.1. This would mean that the actual DG is 60.70.80.1 because 60.70.80.x is masked in?

BR
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

In principle, yes, although I'd be wary if someone told me the default gateway this way.